# How to move database from Firebase to another server?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, firebase, mbaas, nosql

I am a beginner and I am  going to implement an android application that use Firebase but i don't  not know what if I want to move all my database to another server like Amazon Web Service ? is it possible and what type of database engine can I use ?

Comment: I believe there's a data export functionality somewhere in the Firebase UI. It's just JSON, so if you can work out how to import JSON into whatever type of database you choose later, you'll be able to do it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your Firebase dashboard, there's an export button in the upper right corner.

That will export your JSON data into a flat file, which you can then either import into another database that reads JSON data, or craft some code to massage it into a format that's compatible.

You can then use any database engine that works for you.

Please also review the comment from Kato below as there is a limit to how much can be exported from the dashboard.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer but do you know if i can store Arabic Data to fire base?

Comment: That's a different question and should asked separately.

Comment: May also want to mention the [REST API](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/) and the [shallow=true](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/api/#section-param-shallow) argument, for data sets larger than 250MB (which can't be exported in one go via the dashboard).